# Regular weekend away breaks in Europe for non-British Spouse (UK Resident) of a British National

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I am a British National and my wife is Indian and UK Resident. We holiday in europe a lot (always together) and apply for Schengen Visa for her every time we plan a holiday - but this process is time-consuming and we have to book flights, hotel, etc, well in-advance.

We went to a VFS Global office recently, for a visa for our italian adventure and the chap there advised that there is a process whereby I can apply once and every time my wife travels with me, she won't need to apply for a schengen visa for that visit (as long as we are travelling together).

Does anyone know of this or a slightly easier long-term visa, etc, whereby me and my wife can go on last-minute weekend breaks together to europe hassle-free? Much appreciated.

Comment: Whatever procedure it is (even if true), will it apply after BREXIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multiple entry Visa C should solve this problem

- if issued for 1 year

it would allow 60 3 day trips.

All you have to do is select multiple instead of single on the form.

Add a cover letter stating your intension to use it during the year for weekend trips.

---

Make sure the passport has a lot of free pages (3 stamps per visit).

You you, after Brexit, 2 stamps per visit.

Comment: As the spouse of an EU citizen, masterpiece's wife is not subject to the 90/180 rule when they are traveling together, so the visa would allow as many three-day trips as can be squeezed into its period of validity.

Comment: I don't see how the number 60 arises at all. Even if the 90/180 day rule governed one would be able to make a 3-day trip every week _indefinitely_ without ever breaking 90/180 days.

Comment: The question states that at the moment a single visa is being issued. If it isn't needed, it wouldn't be issued. 2*90/3=60.

Comment: The question states that at the moment a single visa is being issued. If it isn't needed, it wouldn't be issued. 2*90/3=60.